# Why does Trish's Stand have a personality of her own?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Stands are physical manifestations of a users fighting spirit and apart from their battle cry, they are usually more like puppets that are controlled by their user. However, Trish's stand has a mind of its own, gave her advise on what to do and even  told her that some of her commands were not the best choice. (Episode 25)

Why does her Stand have a mind of her own? even to the point where she was active before Trish noticed her existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as [Sentient Stands](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Stand_Types#Sentient_Stands):

> Although most Stands do not show any personality or simple hints of it, there are Stands who display a full-fledged consciousness separate from their Users. These Stands are able to think, analyze their environment, and converse with their Users, offering advice or commenting on their actions. Their personalities are diverse, but most sentient Stands follow the command of their Users regardless and act to protect them.

Some other Sentient stands from Part 5 include Sex Pistols and Baby Face.  All of the individual bullets have unique personalities of their own, likewise with Baby Face.